# scaling up the contents whenver window size increases or decreases

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, absolutelayout

Is there any possibilities to **scale** the contents of the **J Frame** For Example : if im giving the initial **setSize(800,1000)** in which i placed the textfields,labels,buttons etc..as per the size 800,1000 the application looks good,suppose im **maximizing the window** of the Frame, automatically the textfields,labels,buttons are kept in the static way...how to scale it when the maximize is pressed the entire contents are cleanly arranged in good manner..kindly give me solution to solve this issue

Comment: What's about LayoutManager? Read specs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: i created a container called c in which i set with the contentpane() the layoutmanager setLayout(null) i gave

Comment: Sergiy is right -- the way to do this is with a layout manager (or quite a few layout managers).  You will need to look them up, read about them, study, and practice, and then you can figure out how to do this with your app.  Sorry, there is no "quick fix" for this, it's a more complicated problem than it seems.

Comment: @SridharRamakrishnan _i set with the contentpane() the layoutmanager setLayout(null)_ That's the worst idea one could have. This always leads to disastrous situation, horrible code to maintain and nightmare code to produce (and then later read). The ONLY way to work is to use appropriate LayoutManager's. Take a look a BorderLayout, GridBagLayout (and if you can have 3rd parties libraries, MigLayout)

Answer (score 1):

> if im giving the initial setSize(800,1000) in which i placed the
>   textfields,labels,buttons etc..as per the size 800,1000 the
>   application looks good,suppose im maximizing the window of the Frame,
>   automatically the textfields,labels,buttons are kept in the static
>   way...

- for `AbsoluteLayout` to have to place the `JComponent` by using the `Insets` that came from first `container`

> Is there any possibilities to scale the contents of the J Frame

- have to use `ComponentListener` (notice delayed by `Swing Timer`, because this `Listener` firing a new event for every pixels on all directions) for scalling `JComponents` together with container
- this is job only for `LayoutManager`, don't to supply that by using `AbsoluteLayout` & `Insets` & `ComponentListener`, be sure this code could be longer an more complicated than by using `GroupLayout`